# Сериализация класса в базу данных

Tags: типы-данных, классы, база-данных, c++

Я написал класс, объект которого заполняется по сети потоком байтов.

```
struct tag
{
    unsigned short * size;
    char * value;
};

class track
{
    public:
        track();
        virtual ~track();
        track(const track& other);
        track& operator=(const track& other);
        void add_tag(unsigned short, unsigned short);
        void set_value(unsigned short, char *); //установка для тега значения
        unsigned short get_size(unsigned short);    //получить размер тега
        void savedb(argument *);
    private:
        std::map <unsigned short, tag> _tags;
};
```

Так вот теперь мне этот класс необходимо сохранить в БД. Проблема заключается в том, что значение value в БД может быть и unsigned short, unsigned int, signed int, singed short, char[15], составной битовый (т.е. значение 1 бита старшего байта, или 4 старших битов байта и т. д.) Возможно ли как нибудь определить по содержимому char[2] что там хранится signed или unsigned? По размеру могу определить int и short.

Comment: не правильно выразился не сам класс, а данные объекта класса